# JSOUP scrape html text from p and span

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm having a hard time getting the correct output. Please see below sample text from HTML:

```
 <p><span class="v">1</span> Een psalm van David. De HEERE is mijn Herder, mij zal niets ontbreken.</p>

 <p><span class="v">2</span> Hij doet mij nederliggen in grazige weiden; Hij voert mij zachtjes aan zeer stille wateren.</p>

 <p><span class="v">3</span> Hij verkwikt mijn ziel; Hij leidt mij in het spoor der gerechtigheid, om Zijns Naams wil.</p>
```

I want to get the value of 

paragraph

 that is **Een psalm van David. De HEERE is mijn Herder, mij zal niets ontbreken.** based on user's selected **verse**

So far this is what I've done:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
HttpResponse resp = client.execute(get);

String content = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

Elements passage = doc.select("p > span.v");

sb.append(passage.text() + "\n");

Elements links = doc.select(className);
for (Element link : links) {
    sb.append(link.text() + " ");
}
Log.e("ELEMENTS", "" + sb.toString());
response = sb.toString();
```

But I'm only getting the verse numbers. How do I get the correct output? I would gladly appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the paragraph of verse `1`, you can do it using:

1. `:has(selector)` to get only elements that contain elements matching the selector
2. Then use as selector `span.v:containsOwn(1)` to indicate that you want a `span` of class `v` whose `text` contains `1`.
3. And finally use `ownText()` to get the text of the element itself not the text of its children too, otherwise if you want both use `text()`.

**So the code could be:**

```
String className = "v";
int verse = 1;
Element p = doc.select(String.format("p:has(span.%s:containsOwn(%d))", className, verse))
    .first();
System.out.println(p.ownText());
```

**Output:**

```
Een psalm van David. De HEERE is mijn Herder, mij zal niets ontbreken.
```

---

If you want to get all paragraphs' content, the code could be:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Elements paragraphs = doc.select("p:has(span.v)");
for (Element p : paragraphs) {
    sb.append(p.ownText() + "\n");
}
System.out.println(sb);
```

**Output:**

```
Een psalm van David. De HEERE is mijn Herder, mij zal niets ontbreken.
Hij doet mij nederliggen in grazige weiden; Hij voert mij zachtjes aan zeer stille wateren.
Hij verkwikt mijn ziel; Hij leidt mij in het spoor der gerechtigheid, om Zijns Naams wil.
```

Comment: thanks man! How about if user chooses other than the first verse?

Comment: simply change the value of the variable `verse` and it should be good

Comment: hey man can you also help me with another problem? I'll send here the link of the question. ty

Comment: Please see this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530066/parse-a-table-from-html-using-jsoup