# Parse a table from HTML using jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I've got another problem with scraping html text. Here's the sample of what I'm trying to extract from:

```
<table class="scripture">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td class="verse" valign="top">
    <a name="2:1"></a><a class="vers" href="javascript:getParallel('LUK', 2, 1);" title="Klik om grondtekst en SV te zien">&nbsp;1&nbsp;</a>
   </td>
   <td class="content">
    <span class="main">En het geschiedde in die dagen dat er een gebod uitging van keizer Augustus dat heel de wereld ingeschreven moest worden.</span>
   </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table class="scripture">
  <tbody>
   <tr>
   <td class="verse" valign="top">
    <a name="2:2"></a><a class="vers" href="javascript:getParallel('LUK', 2, 2);" title="Klik om grondtekst en SV te zien">&nbsp;2&nbsp;</a>
   </td>
   <td class="content">
    <span class="main">Deze eerste inschrijving vond plaats toen Cyrenius over Syrië stadhouder was.</span>
   </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

This is similar to my problem in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40522752/jsoup-scrape-html-text-from-p-and-span/40523112?noredirect=1#comment68286945_40523112) but I want to get the verse text and the Scripture content. How do I achieve this?

So far this is what I've tried:

```
Element table = doc.select("table[class=scripture]").first();
Log.e("BB", "passage1: " + table.ownText());
```

But it doesn't display anything. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you want to get the span's content corresponding to the table that itself contains the verse `2:2`, you can do it with:

```
String verse = "2:2";
// The span of class main located inside the table of class scripture
// that contains a td of class verse with a link whose attribute name is the value of verse
Element p = doc.select(
    String.format("table.scripture:has(td.verse a[name=%s]) span.main", verse)
).first();
System.out.println(p.text());
```

**Output:**

```
Deze eerste inschrijving vond plaats toen Cyrenius over Syrië stadhouder was.
```

Comment: Btw, there are some tables that separate other text such as this: <table class="scripture"><tbody><tr><td class="verse">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="indent">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td class="content"><span class="main">omdat Hij aan mijn rechterhand is, wankel ik niet.</span></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: <table class="scripture"><tbody><tr><td class="verse" valign="top"><a name="16:8"></a><a class="vers" href="javascript:getParallel('PSA', 16, 8);" title="Klik om grondtekst en SV te zien">&nbsp;8&nbsp;</a></td><td class="content"><span class="main"><a href="javascript:toggle(divx3)" title="Tekstverwijzing - klik om deze te zien">&nbsp;<img src="http://herzienestatenvertaling.nl/images/Circle_Orange.png"></a>Ik stel mij de HEERE voortdurend voor <i>ogen</i>;</span></td></tr></tbody></table>

Comment: But they are the same

Comment: If you go to this link: http://herzienestatenvertaling.nl/teksten/psalmen/16/ you might notice when you inspect element that some verses are on new table but they are the same. So the problem there is that how can we determine to merge those two separate verses?

Comment: It is a different problem, so a different question but in a nutshell in this case you will need to iterate over all the table of class scripture and implement your filter programmatically I don't believe that it can be done with a css selector